# What is the best way to remotely edit a file using VS code?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access

Currently, I have two machines, one with Ubuntu in the company and one with Mac OS at home. Sometimes I would like to work at home while accessing the Ubuntu machine in the company. I can ssh into the Ubuntu machine and navigate and compile there. However, when I actually want to edit some cpp source codes, I realize that the editor (VS code) is actually opened in the Ubuntu machine, so I cannot view it from Mac. What should I do if want to edit files remotely on my Mac through VS code?

Though many of the answers mention using version control tools like git, it can be hard to use in my specific case. The problem is that the building environment of my company is Linux, so most of the building tools I have can only run on Linux. This means that I can only compile my source codes in Linux. If I use git, then every time I want to compile and debug my codes, I have to commit and push with my Mac, and then pull and test on Linux. This can be time consuming if want to incrementally modify, test and debug my codes.

Comment: Try out `rsync`. That way you can sync your project files from remote to local, in order to work in real-time. Also, if you're going to use GitHub, you can check out https://exlcode.com/ide which is an online version of VS Code that's integrated with GH -- I may be a bit biased though as I'm a contributor to EXLcode :)

Comment: What kind of file are you editing? Is it some source code?

Comment: Yes, it is some source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/). Then you might edit and compile at home (provided your code is portable between Linux & MacOSX, e.g. because it is POSIX compliant).

You could install some [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server on your Mac and use `ssh -X` to access the remote Ubuntu machine (then run a GUI or editor remotely, e.g. `ssh -X remotelinuxhost.company.com emacs`). However, that requires good bandwidth and latency between your home computer and the remote one.

BTW, you might use some other [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor), like [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (it is capable of [remote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Remote-Files.html) editing) or [vim](http://viml.org/).

Since Linux and MacOSX are both POSIX systems, it is usually (but not always) easy to port source code from Linux to MacOSX and write source code compilable on both systems. BTW, many Linux frameworks (e.g. [Qt](http://qt.io/), [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [Boost](http://boost.org/), etc...) and build systems are usable and ported to MacOSX. Some Linux system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) are not available on MacOSX (e.g. [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)...)

Of course you could install Linux (perhaps inside some VM) on your Apple laptop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am currently using git, but the problem is that the source codes I have on Ubuntu can only be compiled on Linux. Nevertheless, I will definitely try with X11 and source code editors.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what kind of source code do you have that can only be compiled on Linux. Notice that MacOSX is mostly POSIX compatible (like Linux is), so in many (but not all) cases you can quite easily port a Linux source code for MacOSX

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. The source codes I have are cpp source codes. The main problem I have is that the building environment of my company is Linux, so most of the build tools I have can only run on Linux.

Comment: Most of Linux build tools are free software and many of them are ported to MacOSX

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the compatibility between Linux and MacOSX. However, the build tool I use is specifically tailored by our infrastructure team. I think I might be able to get it working for MacOSX, but I believe it would involve some very significant works.